# Cumulative distribution function word problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a word problem regarding the cdf and I am struggling to get my head round the idea. It goes like this:

A dart is thrown at a circular target with radius $\alpha$. The dart always hits the target and The probability that the dart hits any particular region of the target is proportional to the area of that region. Let $R$ be the distance between the target centre and the point the dart hits. I must find the cdf for $R$.

I know that the point of contact is uniformly distributed over the target but that is basically it. If someone can run through how I would do this, it would help greatly.

Comment: $cdf=F(r)=P(R\leq r)$

Comment: Can you find $P(R \leq r)$?

Comment: Can you expand on that please? How would I consider that for $r<0$, $0 \le r \le \alpha$ and $r> \alpha$?

Comment: if $r>\alpha$ then $R\leq r$ always hold so $P(R \leq r)=?$

Comment: $R$ is a distance, so it is non-negative, if $r<0$ then $R\leq r$ never holds so $P(R \leq r)=?$

Comment: 1? I don't really understand what $r$ is. This was for your first question by the way.

Comment: Yes 1 in the first case and 0 in the second case, by $P(R \leq r)$ we mean the probability that the distance of the point the dart hits from the center ($R$) is less than or equal to $r$, i.e. the dart hits somewhere in a circle with radius $r$ around the center.

Comment: Generally, the CDF of a random variable $X$ is $F(x)=P(X \leq x)$.

Comment: Got you. So for the case $0 \le r \le \alpha$ what would I do and how would I join these facts up to find $P(R \le r)$?

Comment: Yes, you are right on, of course it is $0 \leq r \leq \alpha$

Comment: I really don't understand still. Can you provide an answer? What is $P(R \le r)$?

Comment: I wrote the answer, what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

$ F(r) = P(R \leq r)=
  \begin{cases} 
      0    & r<0\\
      \frac{r^2}{\alpha^2} & 0 \leq r \leq \alpha \\
      1    & r>\alpha 
  \end{cases}$

For $0 \leq r \leq \alpha$ the probability is $\frac{r^2\pi}{\alpha^2\pi}=\frac{r^2}{\alpha^2}$